# How can I run Firefox in full-screen mode (no tab bar, no top bar, no address bar), but still see the task bar?

Tags: linux, firefox

I basically want full-screen mode but still be able to see my usual task bar. I want all the bar in the top to be hidden unless I move my cursor to the top. In that case they should just pop up so I can use them normally. How can I make Firefox do this?

Answer (score 0):

By press F11... It will be in fullscreen mode, yet once your mouse cursor hits the top, the tabs will be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>F11</kbd>, then right click on plus (+) sign or nearby it (not on a tab).